# mapStateToProps returns undefined values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
isLoadingDept:true,
isLoadingEmpDesig:true,
isLoadingEmpStatus:true,
isLoadingGroup:true
};

const isLoadingReducer = (state=initialState, action:any) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ISLOADING_Dept":
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {
                isLoadingDept:action.payload  
            };
        case "ISLOADING_EmpDesig":
            return {
               isloadingEmpDesig:action.payload 
            };
        case "ISLOADING_EmpStatus":
            return {
                isLoadingEmpStatus:action.payload
            };
        case "ISLOADING_Group":
            return{
                isLoadingGroup:action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default isLoadingReducer
```

**Store**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import isLoadingReducer from './reducers/isLoadingReducer'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    isLoading: isLoadingReducer
})

export default createStore(allReducers)
```

**Index**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './redux/store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Emp**- file I want to use store in

```
function mapStateToProps(state:any){
  return {
  isLoadingDept: state.isLoading.isLoadingDept,
  isLoadingEmpDesig: state.isLoading.isLoadingEmpDesig,
  isLoadingEmpStatus: state.isLoading.isLoadingEmpStatus,
  isLoadingGroup: state.isLoading.isLoadingGroup
  
  }
 }
class EmpList extends Component<any, any> {
//State and stuff
    
   componentDidMount(){
     console.log(this.props.isLoadingDept)
   }

//stuff
}
export  {EmpList as UnconnectedEmpList};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {forwardRef:true})(EmpList)
```

console log in the last file logs *undefined*. I did this console log because nothing was working as it should, so I wanted to see what's going on. As you can see, I also did console log in Reducer, and it returns a value it should, so that part is working properly.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code of `EmpList `?

Comment: @AniketKolekar I can if you really want, but it's legacy code that doesn't have to do anything with my implementation of Redux (for now). This is all I added on that code. It's also a little big, that's why I excluded it, it would just make it a lot harder to read.

Comment: Can you show us where EmpList is instanciated ? Ensure you import the connected version

Comment: @Topsy it's used in other component as unconnected, cuz I don't need the connected part there, and that's it. I need to use store values in EmpList component

Comment: If you don't use the connected version `EmpList` component, you can pass the state as props from the connected parent component

Comment: @slideshowp2 I could, but there are multiple parent components (4-5), so this makes it more convenient, plus I need those values elsewhere, and I'll need connected EmpList later on anyway, so might as well do it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducers all set one value and since the return value does not reference the original state, throw the rest of the state away, so

```
{
  isLoadingDept:true,
  isLoadingEmpDesig:true,
  isLoadingEmpStatus:true,
  isLoadingGroup:true
};
```

will become

```
{
  isLoadingDept:true,
};
```

To avoid that, do

```js
return {
                ...state,
                isLoadingDept:action.payload  
       };
```

Also, just to make you aware of it: this is a pretty old style of Redux and nowadays we recommend writing that very differently, using the official Redux Toolkit. If you are just learning Redux, you might be following a very outdated tutorial. Please read through [the official "Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) in that case.

Comment: Thanks for help. '...state' was also missing, but I still get undefined when I use "this.props.isLoadingDept" in my Component. As of using the old Redux, thanks for the heads up, but there are a lot more resources for the old one, and tbh, Redux offical documentation is kind of confusing for me, so I use more tutorials than docs.

Comment: That's why I linked the tutorials explicitly. Those really walk you through everything. You'll probably never have to touch the rest of the docs.
As for your problem: You can add a `console.log({state})` to your `mapStateToProps`. That will allow you to make sure that `mapStateToProps` is actually being called and your assumptions about the state contents are correct.

Comment: Then it seems you are still not calling the default-exported connected method. Please validate that all your files are saved and you are 100% sure importing the default export (so without `{}`) from the right file name.